# transform '?oxy_comments' into xml tag

Tags: xml, xslt, oxygenxml, tei

Hej!

is there a way to transform ?oxy_comment_start into a valid xml tag (like `app></app>`) with xslt?

```
<p>
    <?oxy_custom_start type="oxy_content_highlight" color="0,255,0"?>        
    <?oxy_comment_start author="author" timestamp="today" comment="this: is a comment"?>
    THIS
    <?oxy_custom_end?>
    <?oxy_comment_end mid="102"?>
</p>
```

what I want

```
<app>
   <lem>
       THIS
   </lem>
   <rdg> 
      this: is a comment 
   </rdg>
</app>
```

what I've got:

```
<xsl:template match="?oxy_comment_start">
    <app>
        <lem>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </lem>
        <rdg>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name() !='comment']"/>            
        </rdg>
    </app>
</xsl:template>
```

I get the error message:
"Description: Cannot convert the expression {.?oxy_comment_start} to a pattern"

Does anyone know if this is possible and how?

EDIT: more context of my xml and the '?oxy_comment'. And version is: version="2.0", indentation.

Comment: That's not a comment. Those are two [processing instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction) with a text node in between them. Please provide the context in which this appears in your XML.

Comment: In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports - see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: Is that Saxon inside of oXygen XML editor you use/can use, i.e. have you access to the commercial versions of Saxon (PE or EE)? https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/functions/saxon/get-pseudo-attribute.html could help

Answer (score 2):

What you have are 4 [processing instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction) with a text node in-between them.

You can process the 2nd processing instruction using something like:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('oxy_comment_start')">
    <app>
        <lem>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::text()[1]"/>
        </lem>
        <rdg> 
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </rdg>
    </app>
</xsl:template>
```

which should give you:

```
<app>
   <lem>
    THIS
    </lem>
   <rdg>author="author" timestamp="today" comment="this: is a comment"</rdg>
</app>
```

How to parse the value of the `comment` property out of the contents depends on which processor you use. In XSLT 2.0 you could do something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '.*?comment=&quot;(.*?)&quot;.*', '$1')" />
```

assuming there won't be any (escaped) quotes inside the values.

---

Note that you need to be careful not to apply templates indiscriminately from the context of the parent `p`. Or add an empty template to match its text node. Otherwise it will be processed by the [built-in template rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule) and will appear at the output again, after the `app` element.